# Ember.js where to call this._super()

Tags: javascript, ember.js, overriding

I've been going through the Ember documentation and am seeing an inconsistency in where the `_super` method is being called when overriding `init`.

This is the most common and is what I've been using so far

```
var Foo = Em.Object.extend({
    init: function(){
        this._super();
        // ... my stuff ...
    }
});
```

last night I was reading through [this write up](http://emberjs.com/guides/view_layer/) and saw an example doing this

```
var Bar = Em.Object.extend({
    init: function(){
        // ... my stuff ...
        return this._super();
    }
});
```

It was actually an `Ember.ContainerView` in the code snippet.

Can anyone explain this? My code OCD is acting up and I can't move on until I know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the documentation linked

```
 init: function() {
    var childViews = this.get('childViews');
    var descriptionView = App.DescriptionView.create();
    childViews.pushObject(descriptionView);
    this.addButton();
    return this._super();
  },
```

`_super()` is called AFTER the descriptionView is created and pushed onto the `childViews` array.

That's because the superclass `init` implementation is going to take the childViews array and do stuff with it.  If you called `_super` before adding the `descriptionView` to the array, it wouldn't get processed by whatever `init` does....

I'm inferring, but that's the way it works in Sproutcore, from which Ember derives, so I think it's probably the same.

Comment: Ah yes, calling the `super`'s `init` after initializing the `childView` array will remove the overhead of having to render twice.